# Is it best practice that create a new repository for every project?

Tags: svn, version-control, repository

We have 20 projects in a single subversion repository. We divide these projects into different repositories. (Every project is independent from each other). Is this way best practice? So like this:

```
   repository1
     --> trunk
     --> branches

   repository2
     --> trunk
     --> branches

   repository3
     --> trunk
     --> branches

   repository4
     --> trunk
     --> branches
```

Every project must have own repository ? Right?

Comment: one point to consider is, that file externals are only possible within the same repository at the moment

Comment: It depends what you mean by *repository*. A single repository often contains many projects and modules in the structure outlined in your question. See [this link](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.tour.importing.html#svn.tour.importing.layout).

Comment: It will be difficult to manage dependencies and shared projects when have a dedicated repo for a project. Better use a single repo. Any specific reason to have individual repo?

Comment: Yes. I want to independent revision numbers and in redmine independent version numbers. I use redmine. To create a project I have to create a new repository.

Comment: @royalTS This is actually not true. You can use an external from another repository assuming the _SVNParentPath_ is the same. For example, if you have a server with a "repos" directory with a bunch of separate repos in the same parent path, you can use the `svn:externals` property and use `^/../repo_name/path/to/folder` to link to an external in a separate repository.

Comment: @Chris Are you sure about this? The SVN book says: "File externals cannot refer to files from other repositories." http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.advanced.externals.html In the third part.

Comment: @royalTS I’m 100% positive, because it’s exactly what I manage at the company I work for. Go up a little bit from that section to where they’re giving you the syntax for relative paths like `../` or `^/`. Look at the syntax and read the section for `^/../REPO_NAME`. This is how you reference another repository in your externals. As ^ means root, .. means up one directory (SVNParentPath), and the name of the other repo. You’re actually misinterpreting what they’re referring to in the section you quoted. It’s referring to files, not folders. And when you’re committing files, you can only (cont)

Comment: To one repository at a time. You cannot commit to two separate repos with the same exact svn transaction. I actually haven’t tested it out with singular files from other repos, but imagine it should work to be honest.. But folders, work 100%. No question about it, otherwise there wouldn’t be syntax for `^/../REPO_NAME`. That’s the entire purpose of that syntax.

Comment: @Chris I am sorry, but I am quite sure that you misunderstand the section... The path section is only providing a different way (relative) to specify an external definition, either for a file or folder. But the section that I refer to states explicitly that there are some shortcomings for file externals. And one shortcoming is, that file externals cannot use a different repository, independently from the way you specify them

Comment: @royalTS Well, I'll be honest here man, there's not really any point of us going back and forth if you're simply not going to believe me. Here is a screenshot I JUST took with a folder I have called "plugins" that has a list of like 40 externals inside of it, at the bottom, you will see two modules that are in two separate repositories. https://i.imgur.com/zrOJtQY.png

Comment: @royalTS Simply just saying "you misunderstand the section" doesn't mean anything when I can _show_ you that it is 100% possible to work with directories in separate repositories. InternalPlugins and ExternalPlugins in that image are in separate repositories, and you can confirm this by looking at the lines that say WC: Revision. If they were in the same repository, the revision numbers would be the same (or remotely near each other). As I was saying, you can have a checkout folder that contains items from separate repositories.. The SVNParentPath needs to be the same (highlighted).

Comment: InternalPlugins and ExternalPlugins in that image are** separate repositories (typo)

Comment: @Chris I didn't see your picture before posting my comment. But the picture shows external definitions for directories not files? I never questioned the possibility to have folder externals pointing to a different repository. The shortcoming is only about file externals. Actually, I don't how I can make it more clearer... but I will try it once again: an external definition ponting to a file in a different repository is not supported by SVN at the moment. A external definition pointing to a directory in a different repository is possible.

Comment: @royalTS I literally said that....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on your development environment and situation.

In my personal experience at my job, we do a subset of different repositories for entirely different projects (ones that do not have any dependency on projects). However, we also use a "sub-module" type of directory structure when developing a project that has a lot of components to it.

For example, we'll have a core project:

```
  repository1
     --> trunk
     --> branches
```

This repo representing a set of functionality that any project that *includes* this repository can use. Not dependent on any other repositories.

However, I have another repository that I use to develop a bunch of components.

```
  repository2
     module1
       --> trunk
       --> branches

     module2
       --> trunk
       --> branches

     module3
       --> trunk
       --> branches

     module4
       --> trunk
       --> branches

     module5
       --> trunk
       --> branches

     MyModules

     YourModules
```

The reason why I use this approach is because these modules can/will be used by each other. For instance Developer A could be working on a new module, module4 inside of **MyModules**. And in order to get his new module working, he/she needs to use what we refer to as an **[external](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.advanced.externals.html)** to modules 1 and 3. Developer B can be working on a new module as well, module5 inside of **YourModules**. But he/she needs modules 2 and 3.

By using externals with this method, users are able to essentially setup checkout folders (MyModules and YourModules). So when Developer A checks out MyModules, it will respectively checkout modules 1, 3, and 4. Likewise for Developer B who checks out YourModules with 2,3, and 5. The benefit of this being that all users are still "pointing" to the base directories of modules 1, 2, and 3 while being separate sub-projects of each other.

I know it was a bit wordy, but I hope I helped convey a case usage for both methods in question. :)